# I am trying to extract a part of Json response, where i am not able to find the correct regex

Tags: jmeter, json

```
{
"shipToAddress":{
    "country":"SE",
    "zipCode":"AB101AA",
    "emailAddress":"abc@gmail.com"
    },
"deliveryArrangementsId":"DA100000011",
"itemLines":{
    "itemLine":[{
        "unitWeight":"2.3",
        "bundleParentId":"",
        "itemType":"ART",
        "requiredQty":"10.0",
        "unitOfMeasure":"Piece",
        "unitVolume":"1.3",
        "id":"IL1",
        "itemNo":"0000001",
        "volumeUnitOfMeasure":"CUMETER",
        "weightUnitOfMeasure":"KG"
        }]
    },
"businessUnit":{"code":"856","type":"STO"},
"serviceTypes":{"serviceType":[
    {
        "id":"HOME_DELIVERY",
        "possibleSolutions":{
            "possibleSolution":[
                {
                    "service":"STANDARD",
                    "unavailableLines":{
                        "unavailableLine":[
                            {
                                "unavailableQty":"10.0",
                                "itemLineId":"4",
                                "unavailableReasonCode":"NOT_ENOUGH_PRODUCT_CHOICES"
                            },
                            {
                                "unavailableQty":"5.0",
                                "itemLineId":"3",
                                "unavailableReasonCode":"NOT_ENOUGH_PRODUCT_CHOICES"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "id":"HD1",
                    "deliveries":{
                        "delivery":[
                            {
                                "serviceItemId":"SGR40400001",
                                "deliveryId":"1",
                                "unitOfMeasure":"ORDERS"
                            },
                            {
                                "serviceItemId":"SGR40400003",
                                "deliveryId":"2",
                                "unitOfMeasure":"ORDERS"
                            },
                            {
                                "serviceItemId":"SGR40400001",
                                "deliveryId":"3",
                                "unitOfMeasure":"ORDERS"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "earliestShipDate":"2018-12-03T07:00:00.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "service":"CURBSIDE",
                    "unavailableLines":{
                        "unavailableLine":[
                            {
                                "unavailableQty":"10.0",
                                "itemLineId":"4",
                                "unavailableReasonCode":"NOT_ENOUGH_PRODUCT_CHOICES"
                            },
                            {
                                "unavailableQty":"5.0",
                                "itemLineId":"3",
                                "unavailableReasonCode":"NOT_ENOUGH_PRODUCT_CHOICES"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "id":"HD2",
                    "deliveries":{
                        "delivery":[
                            {
                                "serviceItemId":"SGR40400002",
                                "deliveryId":"1",
                                "unitOfMeasure":"ORDERS"
                            },
                            {
                                "serviceItemId":"SGR40400003",
                                "deliveryId":"2",
                                "unitOfMeasure":"ORDERS"
                            },
                            {
                                "serviceItemId":"SGR40400002",
                                "deliveryId":"3",
                                "unitOfMeasure":"ORDERS"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "earliestShipDate":"2018-12-03T07:00:00.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "service":"EXPRESS",
                    "id":"HD3",
                    "deliveries":{
                        "delivery":{
                            "serviceItemId":"SGR40400005",
                            "deliveryId":"4",
                            "unitOfMeasure":"ORDERS"
                        }
                    },
                    "earliestShipDate":"2018-12-01T07:00:00.000Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        "possibleDeliveries":{
            "possibleDelivery":[
                {
                    "shipNode":"CDC.269",
                    "id":"1",
                    "deliveryAssocations":{
                        "deliveryAssocation":[
                            {
                                "itemQty":"10.0",
                                "itemLineId":"1"
                            },
                            {
                                "itemQty":"10.0",
                                "itemLineId":"2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "shipNode":"CDC.027",
                    "id":"2",
                    "deliveryAssocations":{
                        "deliveryAssocation":[
                            {
                                "itemQty":"10.0",
                                "itemLineId":"5"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "shipNode":"CDC.030",
                    "id":"3",
                    "deliveryAssocations":{
                        "deliveryAssocation":[
                            {
                                "itemQty":"5.0",
                                "itemLineId":"3"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "shipNode":"STO.896",
                    "id":"4",
                    "deliveryAssocations":{
                        "deliveryAssocation":[
                            {
                                "itemQty":"10.0",
                                "itemLineId":"1"
                            },
                            {
                                "itemQty":"10.0",
                                "itemLineId":"2"
                            },
                            {
                                "itemQty":"10.0",
                                "itemLineId":"3"
                            },
                            {
                                "itemQty":"10.0",
                                "itemLineId":"4"
                            },
                            {
                                "itemQty":"10.0","itemLineId":"5"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id":"CLICK_COLLECT",
        "possibleSolutions":{
            "possibleSolution":[
                {
                    "service":"STANDARD",
                    "unavailableLines":{
                        "unavailableLine":[
                            {
                                "unavailableQty":"10.0",
                                "itemLineId":"1",
                                "unavailableReasonCode":"NOT_ENOUGH_PRODUCT_CHOICES"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "id":"CC1",
                    "deliveries":{
                        "delivery":[
                        {
                            "serviceItemId":"SGR60000851",
                            "deliveryId":"1",
                            "pickupPoints":{
                                "pickupPoint":[
                                    {
                                        "country":"GB",
                                        "identifier":"PUP1004 Oxford 4 TSP B@IKEA_TSP_B_GB",
                                        "zipCode":"SN1 4BJ",
                                        "openingHoursThuTime":"10:00-21:00",
                                        "distance":"15.91",
                                        "city":"Swindon",
                                        "openingHoursSatTime":"10:00-21:00",
                                        "openingHoursWedTime":"10:00-21:00",
                                        "openingHoursFriTime":"10:00-21:00",
                                        "name":"ICA Maxi Helsingborg",
                                        "openingHoursTueTime":"10:00-21:00",
                                        "addressLine1":"Devizes Road",
                                        "openingHoursSunTime":"11:00-18:00",
                                        "addressLine2":"Devizes",
                                        "openingHoursMonTime":"10:00-21:00",
                                        "addressLine3":"Near Center",
                                        "id":"PUP1004 Oxford 4 TSP B",
                                        "state":"GB",
                                        "addressLine4":"1-3",
                                        "lsc":"LSC.1004"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "country":"GB",
                                        "identifier":"PUP1043 Oxford 4 TSP B@IKEA_TSP_B_GB",
                                        "zipCode":"SN1 4BK",
                                        "openingHoursThuTime":"10:00-21:00",
                                        "distance":"18.01",
                                        "city":"Swindon",
                                        "openingHoursSatTime":"10:00-21:00",
                                        "openingHoursWedTime":"10:00-21:00",
                                        "openingHoursFriTime":"10:00-21:00",
                                        "name":"PostNord",
                                        "openingHoursTueTime":"10:00-21:00",
                                        "addressLine1":"Devizes Road",
                                        "openingHoursSunTime":"11:00-18:00",
                                        "addressLine2":"Devizes",
                                        "openingHoursMonTime":"10:00-21:00",
                                        "addressLine3":"Near Center",
                                        "id":"PUP1043 Oxford 4 TSP B",
                                        "state":"GB",
                                        "addressLine4":"1-3","lsc":"LSC.1043"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
```

In the above response I need to extract the below part:

```
[{"id":"HOME_DELIVERY",
    "possibleSolutions":{
    "possibleSolution":[{
        "service":"STANDARD",
        "unavailableLines":{
            "unavailableLine":[{
                "unavailableQty":"10.0",
                "itemLineId":"4",
                "unavailableReasonCode":"NOT_ENOUGH_PRODUCT_CHOICES"
            },
                {"unavailableQty":"5.0",
                "itemLineId":"3",
                "unavailableReasonCode":"NOT_ENOUGH_PRODUCT_CHOICES"}]}
```

Kindly help me to resolve this

Comment: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ 
Try a beautiflier it will help you a lot! :)

Comment: This part seems to be quite big to be effectively extracted using regular expression. What is your goal? why do you need that part? What are you going to do with that part? Is there any regexp you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your JSON entities are invalid therefore I'm afraid no one will be able to help. To give you some direction you can use [Json Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to filter out "interesting" parts of the source JSON and [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) to produce the new one.

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the "bigger" JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def filter = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$..serviceType[?(@.id == \'HOME_DELIVERY\')].possibleSolutions.possibleSolution[?(@.service == \'STANDARD\')].unavailableLines')
   def newJson = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(filter).toPrettyString()
   log.info(newJson)
   vars.put('newJson', newJson)
   ```

   [image]
3. That's it, you should now be able to refer extracted JSON as `${newJson}` where required

   [image]

References:

- [Groovy Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)